# How to use google apis tasks for javascript

Tags: javascript, task, google-api-js-client

What is wrong with this script?
I'm trying to get the tasklists from google using ggogle apis for javascript.
This is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Google auth</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      function auth() {
        var config = {
            'client_id': '198071236552-5ou4utkvmknkcj48prfah7a4mpm86f5v.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly'
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
            makeTasksApiCall();
        });
      }
      function makeTasksApiCall() {
          gapi.client.load('tasks', 'v1').then(function () {
              var request = gapi.tasks.tasklists.list();

              request.execute(function (resp) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                      var li = document.createElement('li');
                      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
                      document.getElementById('tasks').appendChild(li);
                  }
              });
          });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="auth();">GET CONTACTS FEED</button>
      <div id="tasks">

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:
 gapi.tasks is undefined

Thank you

Comment: shouldn't that be `gapi.client.tasks.taskslists...`?

Comment: yes it should, but gapi.tasks is stil undefined

Comment: Right, because that's the wrong identifier. `gapi.tasks` is not the same as `gapi.client.tasks`